# Softmax choice probabilities with Categorical in PyMC3

Tags: python, theano, pymc3, softmax

I am trying to perform a parameter estimation for a single parameter of a softmax choice function in the following scenario:

In each trial, three option values are given (e.g., [1,2,3]), and a subject makes a choice between the options (0, 1 or 2). The softmax function transforms option values into choice probabilities (vector of 3 probabilities, summing to 1), depending on a temperature parameter (here bound between 0 and 10).

The choice in each trial is supposed to be modelled as a Categorical distribution with trial choice probabilities calculated from the softmax. Note that the choice probabilities of the Categorical depend on the option values and are therefore different in each trial.

Here's what I came up with:

```python
# Generate data
nTrials = 60 # number of trials (value triplets and choices)
np.random.seed(42)
# generate nTrials triplets of values
values = np.random.choice([1,2,3,4,5], size=(nTrials, 3)) 

choices = values.argmax(axis=1) # choose highest value option
# add some random variation, so that *not* always the highest value option is chosen
errors = np.random.rand(nTrials)>0.8 # determine trials with non-optimal choice
# randomly determine new choices for these trials
choices[errors] = np.random.choice([0,1,2], size=sum(errors==True))

# Model specification & estimation
import pymc3 as pm
from theano import tensor as t
with pm.Model():

    # prior over theta
    theta = pm.Uniform('theta', lower=0, upper=10)

    # softmax implementation
    enumerator  = pm.exp(theta*values) 
    denominator = t.reshape(pm.sum(pm.exp(theta*values), axis=1), (nTrials, 1))
    ps = enumerator/denominator

    # Likelihood (sampling model for the data)
    for trial in range(nTrials):
        yobs = pm.Categorical('yobs{}'.format(trial), p=ps[trial], observed=choices[trial])

    # draw 500 samples from posterior
    trace = pm.sample(500, pm.Metropolis())
```

This code fails for nTrials bigger than something like 50 with an extremely long warning / error message:

Warning:

```
INFO (theano.gof.compilelock): Refreshing lock /Users/felixmolter/.theano/compiledir_Darwin-14.4.0-x86_64-i386-64bit-i386-2.7.8-64/lock_dir/lock
INFO:theano.gof.compilelock:Refreshing lock /Users/felixmolter/.theano/compiledir_Darwin-14.4.0-x86_64-i386-64bit-i386-2.7.8-64/lock_dir/lock
00001   #include <Python.h>
00002   #include <iostream>
00003   #include <math.h>
00004   #include <numpy/arrayobject.h>
00005   #include <numpy/arrayscalars.h>
00006   #include <vector>
00007   #include <algorithm>
00008   //////////////////////
00009   ////  Support Code
00010   //////////////////////
00011   
00012   
00013       namespace {
00014       struct __struct_compiled_op_65734e56ae54d89bdcf84e36893358e6 {
00015           PyObject* __ERROR;
00016   
00017           PyObject* storage_V3;
00018   PyObject* storage_V5;
00019   PyObject* storage_V7;
00020   PyObject* storage_V9;
00021   PyObject* storage_V11;
00022   PyObject* storage_V13;
[...]
```

Error:

```
Exception: ('The following error happened while compiling the node', Elemwise{Composite{((Switch(LE(Abs((i0 + i1)), i2), log(i3), i4) + Switch(LE(Abs((i0 + i5)), i2), log(i6), i4) + Switch(LE(Abs((i0 + i7)), i2), log(i8), i4) + Switch(LE(Abs((i0 + i9)), i2), log(i10), i4) + Switch(LE(Abs((i0 + i11)), [...]
```

I am rather new to PyMC (and Theano) and I feel my implementation is really clunky and suboptimal. Any help and advice is strongly appreciated!

Felix

Edit: I've uploaded the code as a notebook, showing the warnings and error messages in full: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/moltaire/softmaxPyMC/blob/master/softmax_stackoverflow.ipynb

Comment: To be able to help, I need the full error message.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've uploaded a notebook with the full error message to github: https://github.com/moltaire/softmaxPyMC/blob/master/softmax_stackoverflow.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

I found again this case. Just as a follow up, now not able able to reproduce it now. So I think it got fixed. We fixed related problem that could hve caused in some case this error.

It work with g++ 4.5.1. If you have this problem update Theano to the development version. If that don't fix it, try to use a g++ more recent, this could be related to older g++ version.